# How to update war files in a docker tomcat container

Tags: tomcat, ssh, docker, war

I've started looking through docs and beginning to understand docker. Created an image using the official tomcat:7-jre7 image and stuck a war in the appropriate place and it starts/stops fine.

My file for reference is :

```
    FROM tomcat:7-jre7
    MAINTAINER: me, me@hotmail.com 
    ADD app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
    EXPOSE 8080
    CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Now that thats all good I have two questions:

1. In the event of something bad, can I ssh in and look at log files or something?
2. How does one update the war file? Is there some way to ssh / scp a new file in?

So far I've tried starting the original image by doing:

```
   docker run -t <_id> /bin/bash
```

and then doing an attach like below from a different session, but that didnt'r do much - all I saw was a black screen.

```
   docker attach <running_container_id>
```

Another way (untested) I thought of was to share the file from the host - hopefully updating the war file will trigger tomcat to redeploy the war file? Has anyone attempted this?

Is there a nicer simpler way to do this?

Thanks for any input, appreciate it.

Comment: I think the idea is that log output is piped to the host (or syslogd or something else outside of the container), and that you update the WAR by rebuilding the docker image.

Comment: Ah, right I see. So some down time and then the service goes along as normal? In the original session that I start docker I can see logs - so Im not overly concerned about that, but updating stuff would be important.

Comment: Re: downtime: I think the idea here is to start the new container while the old one is still running, point the web proxy at the new one, and then shut down the old one.

Comment: Right. Thanks for that. So the container itself then remains immutable and no user data is written to it - or mount a volume and write there so when the container goes down, the volume stays persistent and gets remounted. A more appropriate approach being to make the app contact a db of some sort and store data there? and then make changes to the proxy as you've mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, depending on what you want to do. The easiest option is to simply have the folder for your built war file also contain the Dockerfile you have above. Then, whenever the war file is updated, kick off a docker build and docker run. This could be automated easily with fig as well, with something like:

```
tomcat:
    build: ./war
```

Now just run `fig up` whenever the war file changes and your new container will get built from the Dockerfile in the `war` folder and ran.